# How to connect the application from the monkey talk ide?

Tags: android

How to connect the application from the monkey talk ide?   I am trying to run the android application on monkey talk. I installed android sdk, monkey talk, eclipse, and trying to run the application as per the documentation. but I am failed to run the app, force close occurred every time in emulator . its showing some FATAL exception. please help to get rid of this ...

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.Factory

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at com.mytest.Mymonkeytest1Activity.ajc$preClinit(Mymonkeytest1Activity.java:1)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     at com.mytest.Mymonkeytest1Activity.(Mymonkeytest1Activity.java:1)

10-09 11:05:16.648: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(277):     ... 15 more

10-09 11:05:16.708: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.mytest/.Mymonkeytest1Activity

10-09 11:05:17.288: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44efd5f0 com.mytest/.Mymonkeytest1Activity}

Thanks in advance ....

Comment: Post the lines where the exception is showing. Otherwise no one can help you.